# What is the name for a collective noun for a group of words or acronyms, that is a member of the group it describes?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The same word used to define itself](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54373/the-same-word-used-to-define-itself)

For example TLA is a three letter acronym;
Antepreroxitone (words with the stress on the third from last sylable) is an antepreroxitone;
Noun is a noun.

Comment: Related: [Word used to define itself](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/54373/), [Is there a term for a word that defeats its own purpose?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/23581/), [What is a catchy word that means (non-)self-descriptive](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11422/), [Term for poetry that mimics what it describes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55457/), [A word meaning “looking like the object that it describes”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/42385/), [What do we call this kind of recursive expression?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8577/)

Comment: TLA is a three letter abbreviation or initialism, unless you pronounce it as "tlah".

Answer (score 4):

A word expressing a property which it also possesses itself is said to be *[autological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word)*.

Answer (score 3):

A word that describes a group of words including itself could be called a **self-inclusive** word.

Bertrand Russell could not find anything better than **member of itself** for his famous paradox:

> The class of all classes that are not members of themselves, is or is
>   not a member of itself?

Answer (score 0):

There is a technical mathematical term to describe this situation. It is:

> **impredicative**

which is a definition of an object that presumes the existence of the object in order for the definition to be well-founded. It is related to 'recursive definition' but not identical.